# Renaming multiple folder using command line

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, rename, batch-rename

I am trying to rename multiple folders at once, removing the first few characters of their name:

I found resource around but none of the command that I have tried worked:

```
2 - AT5CRO5JUDBWD4RUPXSQ
4 - LH4FVU3TQDEC87YGN6FL
12 - A878KB79QDIBFOTWB0T8
28 - 5UB5KFD2PK38Z4LS6W80
```

to

```
AT5CRO5JUDBWD4RUPXSQ
LH4FVU3TQDEC87YGN6FL
A878KB79QDIBFOTWB0T8
5UB5KFD2PK38Z4LS6W80
```

Once in the folder I tried:

```
rename "????*" "////*"
rename "....*" "////*"
ren "????*" "////*"
ren "....*" "////*"
rename "....*" "????*"
rename "????*" "????*"
```

Everytime I get a syntax error or that it doesn't match. I really don't understand.
Does anyone have a solution ?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What can and will help in many commands would be to familiarizing yourself with:

---

```
For
For /r 
For /d
Set 
Set string manipulation (substrings)
For loop expanding variables
```

---

- Using a `For`loop you can expand your variable:

```
    %~i   - expands %i removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fi  - expands %i to a fully qualified path file/dir name only
    %~ni  - expands %i to a file/dir name only
    %~xi  - expands %i to a file/dir extension only
    
    %%~nxi => expands %%~i to a file/dir name and extension
```

- ```
  Use the FOR variable syntax replacement:
      %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
      %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
      %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  ```
- ```
  The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:
      %~pnI       - expands %I to a path and file name only
      %~pnxI      - expands %I to a path, file name and extension only
  ```

**Obs**.: About using **`%%~x`** in `directory` name observation note in **`ss64.com`**:

- ```
  Full Stop Bug
  Although Win32 will not recognise any file or directory name that begins or ends 
     with a '.' (period/full stop) it is possible to include a Full Stop in the middle
     of a directory name and this can cause issues with FOR /D.
  ```
- ```
  Parameter expansion will treat a Full Stop as a file extension, so for a directory
  name like "Sample 2.6.4" the output of %%~nI will be truncated to "Sample 2.6" to
  return the whole folder name use %%I or %%~nxI
  ```

---

---

You can do this using a `for /d` loop and `set` to remove everything that comes before (and together) the `*-[space]`:

With `for /d` all directories will be listed in the loop, and their source names will be in `%~nxi`, which can be used in the `ren` command syntax.

For target name, use `!_dir:*- =!`, it will remove everything (`*`) that comes before `-` , and already defining the destination name by expanding in same line the `!_dir!` variable without unwanted characters using `cmd.exe /v:on /c`

For what you have been trying, a use of `for /d` loop and substring `set` in `ren` syntaxes would be resolved by:

```py
for /d %i in (*)do cmd.exe /v:on /c "set "_dir=%~nxi" && move "%~nxi" "!_dir:*- =!""

rem :: or, smaller with the same results...

for /d %i in (*)do cmd/v/c"set "_dir=%~nxi"&&move "%~nxi" "!_dir:*- =!""
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[CMD /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /D Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**

  [√] **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[DelayedExpansion (Refer: `cmd /v /c`)](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**

  [√] **[Substring in Set command (Refer: `!_dir:*- =!`)](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**

---

---

**Obs.:** For do the same in **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**:

```ps1
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -Replace '.* ',''}

# or, smaller with the same results...
gci -ad | ren -New {$_.Name -Replace '.* ',''}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! I am really not used to play with the windows command line and compared to the Linux that I am more used to it seems much more complicated! Thank you very much for your answers and insight on the problem!

Comment: @Unic0 Just a comment, but if you intend to do things at the command line with Windows, Powershell can (arguably) be a better option than batch, depending on the task.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem "Filepath" | Foreach {
  $name = $_.Name.ToString().Split("-")[1].Trim()
  Rename-Item -Path $_.Fullname -NewName $name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell:
VErbose:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Split(' ')[-1] }
```

KeyBanger:

```
gci -ad | ren -New { $_.Name.Split(' ')[-1] }
```